# iphone alertview with textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have an `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField` in it. I want to type the **mail id** and submit in `UIAlertView`'s **ok** button, but `UITextField` in the `UIAlertView` have no response, Please help me.

thankz

Answer (score 19):

From iOS 5 the approach above is no longer necessary. Just set the `alertViewStyle` property to the appropriate style (`UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput`, `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, or `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`).

Example:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Enter your email:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alertView show];
```

and you can have the response back as

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UITextField *emailTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",emailTextField.text);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`UIAlertView` with `UITextField`:

### Usage:

```
NSString *title         = NSLocalizedString(@"Your Title","");
NSString *placeholder   = NSLocalizedString(@"Placeholder Text","");
NSString *message       = NSLocalizedString(@"A message to the user.","");
NSString *cancel        = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel","");
NSString *okay          = NSLocalizedString(@"Continue","");

prompt = [[AlertPrompt alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                   placeholder:placeholder 
                       message:message 
                      delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:cancel 
                 okButtonTitle:okay];
[prompt show];
[prompt release];
```

### .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AlertPrompt : UIAlertView <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *textField;
    NSString *enteredText;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *enteredText;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title placeholder:(NSString *)placeholder message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle okButtonTitle:(NSString *)okayButtonTitle;
@end
```

### .m

```
#import ".h"

@implementation AlertPrompt

@synthesize textField;
@synthesize enteredText;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AlertPrompt Delegates

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title placeholder:(NSString *)placeholder message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle okButtonTitle:(NSString *)okayButtonTitle {

    if (self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:okayButtonTitle, nil])
    {
        self.title      = title;
        self.message      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n",message];
        self.delegate    = delegate;

        UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 75.0f, 260.0, 30.0)]; 
        [theTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
        theTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        theTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        theTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
        theTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        theTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        theTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        theTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        theTextField.placeholder = placeholder;
        theTextField.delegate = self;
        [self insertSubview:theTextField atIndex:0];
        self.textField = theTextField;
        [theTextField release];
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -10); 
        [self setTransform:translate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)show{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [super show];
}

- (NSString *)enteredText{
    return textField.text;
}

- (void)dealloc{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

### Delegate:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Your Title"])
    {    
        if(buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            /*  get the user iputted text  */
            NSString *inputValue = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
            NSLog(@"User Input: %@",inputValue);
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a very explanatory answer +1

Comment: +1 but isn't the use of textfield private? Or at least undocumented? At least it was in 3.x.

Comment: @Jordan No, there's nothing "undocumented" about this example. I actually have 4 apps in the iTunes App Store that use this pice of code, and have had no issues with approval.

Comment: @WrightsCS - I didn't say it didn't work, or that it would not get approved. Just that it is undocumented. Which means the behavior may change down the road.

Comment: @Jordan, no, there's no potential behavior change. This is all standard stuff. What in this example looks like it could possibly change down the road? I mean, with Apple, you are likely to have somethings change, but you roll with the punches and update your code.

Comment: @WrightsCS - OK OK ;) - At the end of the day, you're adding stuff to a UIView. I get it. My point was that UIAlertView wasn't designed for that use case. But it's a moot point. It works, No worries. Have a great day. Cheers.

Comment: self.message      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n",message];
        self.delegate    = delegate;  reqst fro member message ans deligate not a strctr or union,,then i got prompt undclared,lots of errors

Comment: This works great under iOS 4, but with iOS 5 beta, the text box does not display correctly -- it has no border or background, so it looks like you are typing directly onto the UIAlertView and not inside a UITextField. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *emailAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter your Email-id" message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    emailTextField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,45,260,25)];
    [emailTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    [emailTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    emailTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        emailTextField.placeHolder=@"Email";
    [emailAlert addSubview:emailTextField];
    [emailAlert show];
    [emailAlert release];
```

Use UIAlertView Delegates Methods when OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
var alert = UIAlertView(title: "PostActionTitle", message: "PostActionText", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle:"PostActionDecline")
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
alert.addButtonWithTitle("PostActionAccept")
alert.show()
```